# How do I implement Https on asp.net mvc login page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl, https

How do I implement Https on asp.net mvc login page?

Comment: That's a very open ended question... what exactly are you asking...? How do I install a certificate on my IIS server? How I enforce https on a login page? A bit more information about where you are having issues would be good. Does this question help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156748/ssl-pages-under-asp-net-mvc

Comment: enforce on login page only, no other pages.

Comment: So if that's what you want, does the question I pointed you to help you? The RequireSSL attribute?

Comment: You have to config your app server IIS then implementing HTTPS in your application.

The following link can help you.
http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/implemnting-https-everywhere-in-asp-net-mvc-application/

Answer (score 1):

Its a server configuration setting, you need to require HTTPS in IIS.  Of course you will need to buy / generate an SSL certificate first.