# Is there any way to force HTTPS on a Controller Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSL pages under ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156748/ssl-pages-under-asp-net-mvc)

I am thinking there might be something like [UseHttps] but I'm not sure, basically I have a few pages of the site that do a check-out and I want to use secure channel for posting credit card number... but JUST for those couple of Actions, any idea?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156748/ssl-pages-under-asp-net-mvc