# How to enable https in a MVC application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, iis-7, https

i'm desperate. I try to move my MVC Rest service i developed in C# to the HTTPS protocol. I'm normaly java programer, and i admit, i have some serious trouble with the whole configuration of webapps, specially the web.config file which is a big mistery to me.

So, to my problem. I have a working Rest API running on IIS 7. From what i understood, i have to add a binding to the server for https. So i created my custom certificate, and added the binding. In the IIS manager there where now 2 bindings, the http and the https one.

But, as soon as i did this, i couldn't access the webservice over http, or https. Both gave the same error:

The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: context.ListenUriBaseAddress

Googling this error indicated that i need to configure transport security in my web.config file. The problem i have is, that my configuration somehow looks completely different than those in all examples involving the activation of https.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration> 
    <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="None"></authentication>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="CustomBasicAuthenticationModule" type="DMAlertRestServer.Server.Authentificator" />
    </httpModules>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection"
     connectionString="
   Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=DBAlarmTest;Integrated Security=False;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Any hint how this can be solved would really be welcome. thank you very much

Comment: Check out if this link might help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156748/ssl-pages-under-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
I was using WCF library from codeplex. There is a bug there that lets https fail if http is also enabled.
I could circumvent the problem by redoing the routing code.
Sadly i can't post it, because i accidentaly deleted my whole .net project :(