# I have to secure not all but a few pages with ssl?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ssl

I have SSL Certificate but I don't want whole site to encrypt in SSL but few pages like checkout page & payment pages to be set as secure SSL Page so how could I do this?

My website is develop in .net so what should I change in web.confing & code pages?

Comment: Firstly, you need to ensure that the site is hosted under both HTTP (80) and SSL (HTTPS 443). Have you done this already?

Comment: Do you mean MVC, or you've implemented MVP with Web Forms?

Comment: ya i have implementing MVP with web forms.

Comment: @codesleuth no i have only hosted website in http(80).

Comment: You'll need to add the certificate to IIS, and add a binding for port 443.

Comment: ^^ This. As I said, you firstly need to **host** the SSL site, then configure the site to require ssl for certain pages. By the way, this is sounding like a duplicate now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156748/ssl-pages-under-asp-net-mvc

Comment: That question is about MVC, this is about web forms. Maybe there's another one...

Comment: Oh right, I got confused by the flow here.

Comment: You can follow [Jeff Atwood's thoughts](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/should-all-web-traffic-be-encrypted.html). Always use SSL :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a decent [project by Matt Sollars](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5523/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically) you can use to navigate between https and http with Web forms. Just drop in the dll and change the web.config with the relevant settings.

Obviously, you'll need to setup the certificate in IIS too!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll keep them, I didn't have session values when I used it.

Comment: The problem with going back and forth between HTTP and HTTPS pages is that you can never be sure what's been entered securely and what hasn't (even if you've somehow managed to prevent session cookies to be stolen). As a general rule, once you've switched to HTTPS, destroy the old session and never go back.

Comment: @Bruno yes your right we lose our session & cookies. that's why i need the way by which i can switching between http & https safely with retain values.